# Действие при изменении текста внутри тега span

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, text

Есть тег

```
<input type="button" id="left" value="Left">
<span id="year"></span>
<input type="button" id="right" value="Right">
```

В него с помощью jquery выводится текущий год. С помощью кнопок Left и Right (и благодаря jQuery естественно), я изменяю текст/год. Left - отнимает один (2017 - 1), выводится 2016, Right - прибавляет - 2018.

Скажите пожалуйста как отловить событие при изменении текста в span? Допустим если значение изменилось выводим его через alert(). Всем заранее большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: вы же меняете текст в span на нажатие кнопок. Почему прям там не отлаливать?

Answer (score 3):

Как говорится, сам спросил - сам ответил)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#year').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        var txt = $('#year').text();
        alert(sp2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться кастомными событиями jQuery:

При изменении span так же в коде вызывайте событие:

```
$('#year').trigger( "date:changed" );
```

И потом где вам нужно слушаете это событие:

```
$( "#year" ).on( "date:changed", function( event ) {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```